# Extract fixed number of lines if a condition is matched with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I've been doing some research but I think this question is pretty particular.
I want to extract a fixed number of lines from a file when a condition is matched. 
Let's say the file looks like:

```
19287.4342
23213.444443
Time = 0.1
333245.4324
0.2432421
98374532.3241
937463.41
82162.462
762542.16
452621.45
12.019288
Time = 0.2
93891.182
103837.3333
937382.32321
10383.32
163873.22
9821.001
83638.1209
443.232111
Time = 0.3
...
```

And after the extraction I want to get a file for each time `i`. File `0.1.txt` should be:

```
937463.41
82162.462
762542.16
452621.45
```

And `0.2.txt`:

```
10383.32
163873.22
9821.001
83638.1209
```

So I want to extract the lines within the interval [4,7] after every line where `Time = i`, where `i` goes from 0.1 to 10 with an increment of 0.1. Another point of view could be to skip first 3 numbers after `Time = i` and skip last before `Time = i`. But both leading to the same result.

I think this could be done using `awk` and a `for` loop:

```
for i in {0.1..10..0.1}
do
awk -v t="${i}" '{if(($1=='Time') && ($3==t) print (here the interval I want);}' file > ${i}.txt
done
```

Comment: you have to explain the logic of filtering out some number of lines.  Is it by count?  Skip first 3 lines and last 1 line?  Or is it by pattern?  Skip all numeric lines?  What does `i` mean?  Is it the user input?  Also, you need to provide your best effort, even if it's not working, which may include some clues you're not explaining.

Comment: and don't reply in  comments, please fix the problem description in your Q above. Good luck.

Comment: What have you attempted and what errors or other output do you receive? Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your advices and sorry about the lack of accuracy in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question is difficult to understand, it seems you are asking to take each `Time = 0.1` line and then for every line between that time and then next, extract each line consisting of lower-case characters to a filename `0.1.txt` (derived from the `Time = 0.1` line)

With the addition of your attempted code, it is clear you have a misconception about `awk` fields. There is no `$5` (fifth field) present in the input file you show. At most you have 3-fields (using the default space-separated delimiter)

The good news is that it is quite easy to do what you need if I understand what you are asking correctly. You can do it with nothing more than capturing the 3rd field from each line beginning with `Time` and then concatenating `".txt"` to create the filename. Then simply match each line containing `[a-z][a-z]` and redirect that line to the filename using `print`.

For example, given the input of:

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat file
111
222
Time = 0.1
333
444
555
aa
bb
cc
dd
666
Time = 0.2
333
444
555
aa
```

**Example Use**

You can use the short call to `awk` below:

```
awk '
    $1 == "Time" { fname=$3 ".txt"; next }
    /[a-z][a-z]/ { print $0 > fname }
' file
```

**Example Output Files**

The file for `Time = 0.1` (named `"0.1.txt"`) would be:

```
$ cat 0.1.txt
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

and the file for `Time = 0.2` (name: `"0.2.txt"`):

```
$ cat 0.2.txt
aa
```

Look things over and let me know if I understood your question and if you have any further questions about the `awk` expression.

---

**Following Second Edit**

After clarification that you did not want `[a-z][a-z]` as originally shown, but instead wanted the *floating-point* numbers following each `Time = ...` line, the changes needed are minor. Instead of outputting lines that match `[a-z][a-z]`, simply output the lines containing a `'.'` using the regular expression `[.]`.

**Input File**

```
$ cat file2
111
222
Time = 0.1
333
444
555
937463.41
82162.462
762542.16
452621.45
666
Time = 0.2
333
444
555
10383.32
163873.22
9821.001
83638.1209
666
```

**`awk` Usage***

```
$ awk '$1 == "Time" {fname=$3 ".txt"; next} /[.]/{print $0 > fname}' file2
```

**Output Files**

```
$ cat 0.1.txt
937463.41
82162.462
762542.16
452621.45

$ cat 0.2.txt
10383.32
163873.22
9821.001
83638.1209
```

---

**Edit Three - Extract Lines 4-7 Following "Time"**

Ok, since you have now designated that you wish to extract lines 4-7 following each `"Time = ..."` line, you can do essentially the same thing, but instead of looking for e.g. characters, or floating-point numbers, you simply keep a counter of the number of lines after the `"Time = ..."` line and output values to each file when `count > 3 && count < 8`. For example:

```
awk -v count=8 '
    $1 == "Time" {fname=$3 ".txt"; count=1; next}
    count > 3 && count < 8 {print $0 > fname}
    {count++}
' file2
```

Initially sets the counter to not-match anything. Then when `"Time = ..."` is encountered, it creates the filename and sets `count=1`. the `{count++}` group will increment `count` for each records read, and the group `count > 3 && count < 8 {print $0 > fname}` extracts lines 4-7 when they are encountered.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat file2
19287.4342
23213.444443
Time = 0.1
333245.4324
0.2432421
98374532.3241
937463.41
82162.462
762542.16
452621.45
12.019288
Time = 0.2
93891.182
103837.3333
937382.32321
10383.32
163873.22
9821.001
83638.1209
443.232111
```

Then using:

```
$ awk -v count=8 '
    $1 == "Time" {fname=$3 ".txt"; count=1; next}
    count > 3 && count < 8 {print $0 > fname}
    {count++}
' file2
```

Will produce the desired output files:

**Example Output Files**

```
$ cat 0.1.txt
937463.41
82162.462
762542.16
452621.45

$ cat 0.2.txt
10383.32
163873.22
9821.001
83638.1209
```

Hopefully we have now gotten to the actual problem you needed to solve `:)`

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood it (I'm gonna edit it now). The lines that I want to appear in each file aren't char type, I only used that to illustrate it better but I think I'm gonna edit it again and see if I can make it clearer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sorry about that but the numbers 333, 444 ... are also floating-point. I forgot about it. I'm editing again.

Comment: @dolfus with that edit, you will have to explain the exact logic needed to extract the numbers you want. Skip first 3 numbers after `Time = ...`, skip last before `Time = ...`? Please edit your question and explain that logic so it is clear. At this point we have gone from example input containing integers and characters, to example input containing mixed integer and floating-point, to now lines of only floating-point. What is the criteria for selecting the floating-point numbers you want?

Comment: I already edited it a few days ago. I think now is less confuse.